# Python 2/3 converting big ints to bytes and back?

Tags: python

Is there a good cross-version (Python 2 and Python 3 compatible) way of converting arbitary sized long integers to arrays of bytes and back (both little and big endian)?

I only found one solution to convert byte array to int:

```
int(codecs.encode(dat, 'hex'), 16)
```

Comment: See the duplicate, which includes a cross-Python-compatible answer. Your own code suffices to go the other way, or use `int(binascii.hexlify(dat), 16)`

Comment: Added two more links for some more suggestions.